# I cannot use SOCKS5 proxy with node fetch (FetchError. reason: Socket closed)

Tags: node.js, docker, proxy, httptosocks5proxy

I have a Docker container running [this](https://hub.docker.com/r/yarmak/warp-proxy) image on my machine (it's a SOCKS proxy server) and I have exposed the needed ports needed for it to work. And when I run `curl -x socks5://localhost:40000 https://ip.me` on my machine, the requests goes through fine and everything works. But when I try to send a request from node using the proxy agent, it doesn't work. Here is my code:

```js
const fetch = require('node-fetch')
const { SocksProxyAgent } = require('socks-proxy-agent')

const req = await fetch(`https://google.com`, {
    agent: new SocksProxyAgent(`socks5://localhost:40000`)
})

console.log(req.ok)
console.log(req.status)
```

Here is my error:

```
/home/______/______/node_modules/node-fetch/lib/index.js:1376
                        reject(new FetchError(`request to ${request.url} failed, reason: ${err.message}`, 'system', err));
                               ^
FetchError: request to https://google.com/ failed, reason: Socket closed
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/home/______/______/node_modules/node-fetch/lib/index.js:1376:11)
    at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:390:28)
    at onerror (/home/______/______/node_modules/socks-proxy-agent/node_modules/agent-base/dist/src/index.js:117:21)
    at callbackError (/home/______/______/node_modules/socks-proxy-agent/node_modules/agent-base/dist/src/index.js:136:17) {
  type: 'system',
  errno: undefined,
  code: undefined
}

Node.js v17.0.0
```

I'm not sure why this is happening. Can anyone try to help?

Answer (score 2):

It was an error with my code. I wasn't waiting for the container to fully start up before I was using it.

Comment: What did you mean by saying ccontainer? (i have the same issue and looking for solution)